# Update git remote repo on push

Tags: git

ON A SERVER

- I created a git repo in the working
  directory of my web-app /html.
- To create a git 'host' repo, I ran
  `git clone --bare html html.git`.
- I now have a git 'host' repo and a
  git 'client' repo on the remote
  server at /html.git (host) & /html
  (client).

I want to push from my local machine to the server and not have to do a `git pull` ON THE SERVER.

ON MY LOCAL MACHINE

When I push from my local machine to the remote 'host' repo, I want to use the post-receive hook to run a `git pull` on the remote 'client' repo.

**Is this possible or is this the easiest way of doing this?**

Going to be trying to use this method: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

Comment: Are you trying to get the remote repository to pull the client repository on your local machine, or somewhere else? If the answer is the former, why not just push them both at the same time?

Comment: I'm trying to get the remote client to pull from the remote host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible. The git hooks are just ordinary scripts that are given some useful arguments, so (assuming the git user has access to both repos) you should be able to do something like:

```
cd /path/to/client/repo && git pull host master
```

Comment: This worked - A good walkthrough here: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `git pull` in the remote 'client' repo, you can directly push from the 'host' repo into the client.

In /path/to/host/repo/.git/hooks/post-receive, just have something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
git push ../html master
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to push to a 'client' repo like that.. I think I should be able to push from my local computer TO the client repo on the server.